# How to use regex to match an IPFS URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have the following IPFS URL.

`https://example.com:2053/ipfs/QmPQeMz2vzeLin5HcNYinVoSggPsaXh5QiKDBFtxMREgLf/images/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001.png`

I want to use regex to match this file, but instead of writing the full URL, I want to just match something like `https*00000001.png`.

The problem is that when I use

```
  paddedHex = '00000001';
      let tmpSearchQuery = `https*${paddedHex}.png`;
```

It doesn't really match anything. Why?

Comment: `https*${paddedHex}.png` matches `httpssssssssssssssssss00000001.png`, `https00000001.png`, and `http00000001.png`, but doesn't match `https879kjhd*&^%#*&TI*#00000001.png`, because you're matching 0 or more `s`s, not wildcard. You can do `https.*${paddedHex}.png`.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating an `s` char zero or more times using `s*` and to create a dynamic regex you have to use the RegExp constructor.

You can repeat optional non whitespace chars instead using `\S*` and if you want to match http and https make the s optional using `s?`

```js
const s = `https://ipfs.moralis.io:2053/ipfs/QmPQeMz2vzeLin5HcNYinVoSggPsaXh5QiKDBFtxMREgLf/images/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001.png`;
const paddedHex = '00000001';
const tmpSearchQuery = new RegExp(`https?\\S*${paddedHex}\\.png`);
const m = s.match(tmpSearchQuery);

if (m) {
  console.log(m[0]);
}
```